# Python Sorted by Index

Tags: python

Lets say there is a dictionary

```
foo = {'b': 1,  'c':2,  'a':3 }
```

I want to iterate over this dictionary in the order of the appearance of items in the dictionary.

```
for k,v in foo.items():
    print k, v
```

prints

```
a 3
c 2
b 1
```

If we use sorted() function:

```
for k,v in sorted(foo.items()):
    print k, v
```

prints

```
a 3
b 1
c 2
```

But i need them in the order in which they appear in the dictionary i;e

```
b 1
c 2
a 3
```

How do i achieve this ?

Comment: [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dictionaries have no order. If you want to do that, you need to find some method of sorting in your original list. Or, save the keys in a list in the order they are saved and then access the dictionary using those as keys.

From [The Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

> It is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of key: value
>   pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one
>   dictionary).

Example -

```
>>> testList = ['a', 'c', 'b']
>>> testDict = {'a' : 1, 'c' : 2, 'b' : 3}
>>> for elem in testList:
        print elem, testDict[elem]


a 1
c 2
b 3
```

**Or better yet**, use an [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) -

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> testDict = OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('c', 2), ('b', 3)])
>>> for key, value in testDict.items():
        print key, value


a 1
c 2
b 3
```

Comment: Or use an ordered dict - part of the standard library as of 2.7, and a common recipe for earlier versions.  http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: Yes. Was just adding. Thanks. :)

Comment: your output is wrong for OP's question, a,c,b is the wrong order, should be b,c,a

Comment: I don't think that matters since the order is maintained across my test cases. He can choose to change that to any order he wants.

Comment: Your example with OrderedDict is wrong. Well, it **happens** to be right for this case, but it won't for others. That's because you're passing it a regular dict, which loses the order and only then does the OrderedDict get initialized. Instead, you should pass it, say, a sequence of tuples: `OrderedDict([('b',1), ('c', 2), ('a', 3)])`

Answer (score 2):

An [ordered dictionary](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) would have to be used to remember the order that they were stored in

```
>>>from collections import OrderedDict
>>>od = OrderedDict()
>>>od['b'] = 1
>>>od['c'] = 2
>>>od['a'] = 3
>>>print od
OrderedDict([('b',1), ('c',2), ('a',3)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this?

```
sorted(foo, key=foo.get)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use your OrderedDict multiple times, use an OrderedDict like people have said.  :)  If you just want a one-liner for a one-off, change your sort function:

```
sorted(foo.items(), lambda a,b:a[1]-b[1])
```

Comment: +1, but AFAIK, python docs suggested to use keys instead of comparators

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by one-liner:

```
>>> sorted(foo.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
[('b', 1), ('c', 2), ('a', 3)]
```

Comment: while this worked in the small example i gave above, it did not sort in my actual code which is fairly larger than this

Comment: well it's strange, could you provide a sample from your dictionary?

Comment: well I just found that I have not read your question entirely, I though you want to sort dictionary by values (which my code does in both cases). As dictionary is unordered, there's no garanteed order, so you have to use OrderedDict

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to sort them by the keys do:

```
sorted_by_keys_dict = dict((y,x) for x,y in foo.iteritems())
for k,v in sorted(sorted_by_keys_dict.items()):
    print v, k

a 1
c 2
b 3
```

or simply:

```
for k,v in sorted(dict((y,x) for x,y in foo.iteritems()).items()):
    print v, k

a 1
c 2
b 3
```

Answer (score 1):

The see this more directly, the order you used to create the dict is not the order of the dict.  The order is indeterminate.

```
>>> {'b': 1,  'c':2,  'a':3 }
{'a': 3, 'c': 2, 'b': 1}
```